How do I order the variables displayed in table for tbl_uvregression?
I would like to make a table in gtsummary with the variables listed in this order from top to bottom:
covars <- c("age", "stage", "grade", "marker", "response")

I ran this code but the table lists the variables in a different order (age, marker, stage, grade, response).
tbl_uvregression(
  trial,
  method=coxph,
  y=Surv(ttdeath, death),
  exponentiate = TRUE,
  include = all_of(covars),
  hide_n = TRUE,
  add_estimate_to_reference_rows = TRUE) %>%
  as_kable()




Characteristic
HR
95% CI
p-value




Age
1.01
0.99, 1.02
0.332


Marker Level (ng/mL)
0.91
0.72, 1.15
0.435


T Stage





T1
1.00
Reference



T2
1.18
0.68, 2.04
0.560


T3
1.23
0.69, 2.20
0.476


T4
2.48
1.49, 4.14
4.7e-04


Grade





I
1.00
Reference



II
1.28
0.80, 2.05
0.305


III
1.69
1.07, 2.66
0.024


Tumor Response
0.50
0.31, 0.78
0.003




It seems that include doesn't honor the variable ordering. You may have to select the data frame first before calling tbl_uvregression:
covars <- c("age", "stage", "grade", "marker", "response")

select(trial, all_of(covars), ttdeath, death) %>%
  tbl_uvregression(
    method=coxph,
    y=Surv(ttdeath, death),
    exponentiate = TRUE,
    #  include = all_of(covars),
    hide_n = TRUE,
    add_estimate_to_reference_rows = TRUE)



